# Not able to see the cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the data from backend & I am passing the data to Product.js. But Cards are not coming only search bar is coming. I am able to see the data in console using `console.log(this.state.products);`. Imports are there.
Here is my `Products.js` file content.

```
import Product from "./Product";

class Products extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      searchString: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9022/products/getAll").then(res => {
      this.setState({ products: res.data });
      console.log(this.state.products);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products ? (
          <div>
            <TextField
              style={{ padding: 24 }}
              id="searchInput"
              placeholder="Search for products"
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.onSearchInputChange}
            />
            <Grid container spacing={24} style={{ padding: 24 }}>
              {this.state.products.map(currentProduct => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                  <Product products={currentProduct} />
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </div>
        ) : (
          "No products found"
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

**Here is my Product.js file content.**

```
const Product = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.product ? (
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2">
              {props.product.fields.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">{props.product.fields.id}</Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: In you product component use props.products and not props.product or change <Product product={currentProduct} /> (removing s from products attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a typo. Its `props.producs` but not `props.product`. You are passing `products` as a prop to `Product` component but accessing as `props.product` so you need to access it using `props.products`. Try the below corrected code

```
const Product = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
          { props.products ? (
                <Card>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2">
                            {props.products.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                            {props.products.id}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
          ): null }  
        </div>
    )
}
export default Product;
```

Also when you do .map or .forEach or for loop you should add unique id as key to the parent jsx element inside loop. iN your code you need to add unique like below

If you have unique id from each currentProduct then do this

```
   { this.state.products.map(currentProduct => (
          <Grid key={currentProduct.id} item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product products={currentProduct} />
          </Grid>
   ))}
```

otherwise add index as key like below

```
   { this.state.products.map((currentProduct, index) => (
          <Grid key={`Key_${index}`} item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product products={currentProduct} />
          </Grid>
   ))}
```

Comment: Now Cards are coming but All are coming in complete white.

Comment: Check whether you are rednering the data properly to cards. or do you want to set banground color to the card?

Comment: how's your this.state.products data looks like?

Comment: Array(6)
0: {id: "5", title: "docx", price: "353"}
1: {id: "8", title: "hi", price: "85"}
2: {id: "2", title: "msg", price: "23"}
3: {id: "4", title: "Javad", price: "4"}
4: {id: "1", title: "pdf", price: "13"}
5: {id: "3", title: "pdf", price: "27"}

Comment: Now Its coming. Thank You.